# log in yii2 account using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, yii2, alamofire

I'm trying to log in into account using api and POST request in Swift 3 with Alamofire library. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func logInButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        Alamofire.request(".../api/login", method: .post, parameters: ["email": "mail1@gmail.com", "password" : "qwerty"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { (response) in
            if let result = response.result.value {   
                print(result)
            }
        }

    }
```

When I'm trying to get an access_token field (user exists and api works correctly, for sure) from this request, I am not getting it.

The fact is my api user's url is always the same (I've already read this: [How to pass access token to Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799069/how-to-pass-access-token-to-alamofire)) and looks like ".../api/login/" and it doesn't depend on user e-mail or username, and I don't know how I should deal with it in a such way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print the response object and see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: @Jaseem Abbas, `{"messageType":"error","message":{"email":["«Email»."],"password":["«Password»."]}}`

Comment: It looks like your server is rejecting the call. Your code seems to be correct.