# Adding Firebase IdToken with Completion Handler to Every AlamoFire Request

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, alamofire

I understand how to add customer HTTP Requests headers, such as Authorization Tokens, [like this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799069/how-to-pass-access-token-to-alamofire)

My complication is around using the Firebase API to get the bearer token because it has a completion handler in the event the bearer token has expired, the refresh token is used to try and get a fresh bearer token:

```
static func getIdToken(completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
    guard let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        print("No Firebase User!")
        completion(nil, nil)
        return
    }

    user.getIDToken { (idToken, error) in
        if(error != nil ) {
            print("AuthUtiltiy, error retrieving token: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }

        completion(idToken, nil);
    }
}
```

I have started to abstract around the AlamoFire SessionManager where I can add additional HTTP Request Headers:
    class LibraryAPI: NSObject {

```
private var manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

// Setups the cookie and shared instance
override init() {
    let defaultHeaders = manager.session.configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders
    manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
}
```

But because of this callback/completion handler in the Firebase getIdToken call, I cannot do achieve adding an auth token to every request in the my abstraction init.

I also tried to wrap up my actual HTTP requests using AlamoFire but I still have the same issue.

I do not think I can use a `RequestAdapter`, [introduced in AlamoFire 4.0](https://grokswift.com/custom-headers-alamofire4-swift3/), again because of the same Firebase.getIdToken Callback/Completion handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to support this in Alamofire 4 due to `RequestAdapter` being synchronous, as you noted. However, in Alamofire 5 (currently in beta) `RequestAdapter` was updated to be asynchronous for exactly the reason posted here. Updating, if you can, would be the easiest way to elegantly support this case.